# IcoMoon error al mostrar icono/caracter

Tags: html, css, web

Estoy realizando una maquetación y probando [IcoMoon](https://icomoon.io/) para los iconos de las redes sociales. Creé mi repositorio, lo descargué y lo implementé pero al cargar la página muestra un error de carácter en vez del icono esperado, estuve intentando depurarlo pero sin éxito.

Les dejo el código que utilicé:

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: 'icomoon';
  src:  url('fonts/icomoon.eot?rtaxuw');
  src:  url('fonts/icomoon.eot?rtaxuw#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
    url('fonts/icomoon.ttf?rtaxuw') format('truetype'),
    url('fonts/icomoon.woff?rtaxuw') format('woff'),
    url('fonts/icomoon.svg?rtaxuw#icomoon') format('svg');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}

[class^="icon-"], [class*=" icon-"] {
  /* use !important to prevent issues with browser extensions that change fonts */
  font-family: 'icomoon' !important;
  speak: none;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-variant: normal;
  text-transform: none;
  line-height: 1;

  /* Better Font Rendering =========== */
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}

.icon-twitter:before {
  content: "\f099";
}
.icon-facebook:before {
  content: "\f09a";
}
.icon-facebook-f:before {
  content: "\f09a";
}
.icon-github:before {
  content: "\f09b";
}
.icon-linkedin:before {
  content: "\f0e1";
}
```

```html
<head>

 <meta name="description" content="Wordpress theme Global">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 <title>Wordpress Theme</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/reset.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/responsive.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/icomoon/style.css">
</head>

<body>

 <header>
  <div id="top_header">
   <div id="logo"><a href="#"><img src="img/log.png"></a></div>
   <div class="no_show_responsive">
    <div id="social">
     <ul>
      <li><a href="http://facebook.com/" ><span class="icon-linkedin"></span></a></li>
      <li><a class="tw" href="http://twitter.com/"><img src="img/tw.png" ></a></li>
      <li><a class="gl" href="http://google.com/"><img src="img/gl.png"></a></li>
     </ul>
    </div>
```

Comment: El código `CSS` ¿a que archivo pertenece? Dentro del proyecto, la ruta completa a las fuentes ¿acaso es `css/icomoon/fonts/`?

Comment: Probablemente ese error debe ser que no encuentra la ruta de la fuente que utiliza el paquete de iconos. Verifica que las rutas hacia la fuente este correctas. En el inspector puedes irte a la pestana de Elements(Chrome), luego te vas a las etiquetas <head> y verificas las rutas de los font's.